# fliping view continiously

Tags: iphone, core-animation

this my code

```
[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:1.5];  
    if ([sender tag] == 1) {
        [UIView setAnimationTransition:UIViewAnimationTransitionFlipFromLeft forView:placeholder cache:YES];
    }
    else {
        [UIView setAnimationTransition:UIViewAnimationTransitionFlipFromRight forView:self.view cache:YES];
    }
    if (view1OnTop) {
        [view1 removeFromSuperview];
        [placeholder addSubview:view2];
    }
    else {
        [view2 removeFromSuperview];
        [placeholder addSubview:view1];
    }
    [UIView commitAnimations];

    view1OnTop = !view1OnTop;
```

i want to continuously flip the view, for say some duration 1 min.

it should be continuously flipping.

how can i do it.
what i m trying to is, i want a view, which should be continuously flipping for some particular amount of time.
how can i achieve this?
regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apart from the flipping animation, which I presume you have working, you need to initiate a new animation when the current one is finished.

Before [UIView commitAnimations], do this:

```
[UIView setAnimationDelegate:self];
[UIView setAnimationDidStopSelector:@selector(animationDone:finished:context:)];
```

add a function

```
-(void)animationDone:(NSString*)id finished:(NSNumber*)n context:(void*)context
```

and let that fire the next round.

**edit:** you do this by putting in the code to fire an animation, so the typical block from `[UIView beginAnimations...]` to `[UIView commitAnimations]`. The better solution of course is to put the animation starting code in a separate function, so the outline will look like:

```
...
    [self startAnimationLoop];
...

-(void)startAnimationLoop
{
    [UIView beginAnimtions...];

    // do the animation stuff

    [UIView setAnimationDelegate:self];
    [UIView setAnimationDidStopSelector:@selector(animationDone:finished:context:)];
    [UIView commitAnimations];
}

-(void)animationDone:(NSString*)id finished:(NSNumber*)n context:(void*)context
{
    [self startAnimationLoop];
}
```

to make it go back/forth, add some state variable, or create 2 sets of these functions which call eachother (`startAnimationLoop1` and `startAnimationLoop2`, each one firing the other when done)

Comment: Thanks mvds

i just wanna knw 1 thing, what should i write in animationdone function.????

Comment: edited the answer to make it more explicit. Furthermore I suggest you go and experiment, all the ingredients are there.