# moving uiimage view on screen

Tags: iphone, core-animation

I want an image view of some size say 25 by 25, to move in a linear motion from left to right and then right left continuously.

Lets say the image starts moving from left, then at the time it reaches reaches the right, it should start moving back to the left, then this should repeat.

I have this code, which lets the view move down, but I am unable to move it back and forth. This is for UIView.

```
[UIView beginAnimations:@"MyAnimation" context:nil];
[UIView setAnimationBeginsFromCurrentState:YES];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:45.0]; // 5 seconds
frame = movingView.frame;
//int j = frame.origin.y;
int i;
for (i= 0; i<=100; i++) {
    frame.origin.y += i;//100.0; // Move view down 100 pixels
    movingView.frame = frame;
}
```

How should i do this?

Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have to animate things yourself when using UIView animations.

```
frame = movingView.frame;
frame.origin.x = 0;
movingView.frame = frame; // starting point

[UIView beginAnimations:@"MyAnimation" context:nil];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:5];

frame.origin.x = 320-25;
movingView.frame = frame; // endpoint

[UIView commitAnimations];
```

for a move from left to right. To wait for the end, use `setAnimationDidStopSelector` to call a method which does the opposite animation.

Have a look at [flipping uiview continuously](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3253310/3255870) for the animation delegate stuff.

Comment: Thanks mvds

i knw setAnimationDidStopSelector is called like this.
 [UIView setAnimationDelegate:self];

But where should do this, i am not getting the opposite animation

regards

Comment: please update your question to show your current code, or we'll be entertaining eachother all day...

Comment: added a link to kind of the same question I answered yesterday.

Comment: hey mvds
i tried this code to move my image view up, and ow i want to move the image view back to its original postion in animation.....like a coin going up and than falling back type of animation.
frame = coinImageView.frame;
 frame.origin.x = 120;
 coinImageView.frame = frame; // starting point 
 [UIView beginAnimations:@"MyAnimation" context:nil];
 [UIView setAnimationDuration:3]; 
 frame.origin.y = 160-100;
 coinImageView.frame = frame; // endpoint 
 [UIView setAnimationDelegate:self];
 //[self backToGround]; 
 [UIView commitAnimations];
how can i make my view back as it gets top of screen

Answer (score 3):

It seems you might be making this more complicated than it needs to be. Animate the view *center* rather than its *frame*.

```
  [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
  [UIView setAnimationRepeatAutoreverses:YES];
  [UIView setAnimationRepeatCount:HUGE_VAL];
  [UIView setAnimationDuration:5.0];
  // Animate to right side of the containing view
  [movingView setCenter:CGPointMake([[self view] bounds].size.width - 
                     [movingView bounds].size.width / 2.0, 
                     [movingView center].y)];
  [UIView commitAnimations];
```

This will animate the view's center to the right side of the containing view and then automatically return to the start position. Notice I subtract out half of the *movingView*'s width since we're wanting to animate to the right side but we're moving the view's *center* not its *origin*.

Setting auto reverse repeat to YES will cause the animation to end up back where it started and then repeat count will cause it to repeat forever.

Also, there is no reason to move the view down one pixel at a time. Just set the ending position you want the view to have and specify an appropriate duration it should take to get there. Core Animation eliminates the need for you to create your own animation loops, timers, or threads.